# 'DOMPDF_Exception' with message 'Unable to find a suitable font replacement for: 'serif''

Tags: pdf-generation, dompdf

I get this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMPDF_Exception' with message 'Unable to find a suitable font replacement for: 'serif'' in /home/users4/p/www/website/lib/dompdf-0.5.2/include/style.cls.php:793
```

with the basic example :

```
require_once("lib/dompdf-0.5.2/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$html =
 '<html><body>'.
 '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
 'templating system.</p>'.
 '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render(); //<--- this line generate the error
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

I set permission on "/lib/" in 777. I put all the folder "dompdf-0.5.2" in my FTP (PHP 5.2+). 
I searched in Google a solution but nothing helped me.

If you need more informations, let me know... I am lost...

EDIT : I tested in local, I have the same problem, this is the screen on the error with xDebug : http://snag.gy/10yIg.jpg

Answer (score 1):

A friend give me an other version "dompdf_0.6_b2" and it works perfectly...

Comment: Odd. Could have been a corrupt download (we've seen that on occasion). Also, there's a beta 3 out with improvements you might want to try. https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases